# What should our chat room be named?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

This is a typical question that comes up during the beta process. I just realized that chat for Sound Design wasn't really ever set up after it moved to the Stack Exchange 2.0 platform, and I'm here to fix that!

In case you didn't know, we have chat, and it's awesome! Click on the Stack Exchange icon at the top left of your screen while browsing Sound Design and then click the chat link - you'll go to a page full of chat rooms associated with the site.

I've created [a generic chat room for you](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12703/sound-design-general-chatter) - but the name and description is quite bland and boring. We can do better, so let's use this post to come up with a better name for chat.

For instance, our site for Aviation named their room "The Hangar", our site for pets named their room "The Litterbox". The name can be creative and a little funny, but should remain obvious to someone new that this is the room to come and chat about sound.

Have fun, and may the best name win!

***Update***

[The echo chamber](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13350/the-echo-chamber) is now available for chat! Enjoy! Don't forget, you can create additional rooms as you like, we only ask that they relate to the topic of the site (sound design, or topics closely surrounding it).

Answer (score 9):

'The echo chamber', it's nice (i think) and funny (if there's no other people to chat to).

Comment: Hehehe, well, it certainly reminded me to get back in that room after my browser crashed yesterday!

Comment: Or perhaps 'Impulse Response'

Comment: Anechoic Chamber?

Comment: @endolith: yes, but it would sound pretty much dead ;)

Comment: very nice. love it.

Comment: thanks for the support!

Answer (score 4):

How about

> The Studio

It's simple but suggestive.

Comment: Nice... or in that same vein... "The Control Room" or "Behind the Glass", etc.

Comment: or possibly The Recording Studio.  The Studio is a little less clear about topic

Answer (score 4):

The Infinite Baffle

Don't know why, just thought it sounded cool. Also thought of "The Headroom" or "The Wavelength" but they seemed a bit smug.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- The padded room
- Recording Booth
- Control Room
- Mixing Deck
- The Soundscape
- [Waveform City](http://wiard.com/modular/300series/waveformcity/)
- Bleeps and Bloops

Comment: heh, Padded Room... kinda funny :)

Comment: should split these into separate answers so they can be voted for independently

Answer (score 0):

I would call it ADR or Voice-Over :)